# How to modify an object hash's value in a template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How to declare a new value for `settings.color` using handlebars syntax or an Ember.js helper before the `settings` object is consumed by the `bar` component?

eg.

```
foo-component.js
    settings: { color: "blue", size: 16, ...many others }
foo-template.hbs
    {{yield settings=settings}}

my-route.hbs
    {{#foo as |settings|}}
        #! How to change `settings.color` to "red" here before passing to bar  ? !#
        {{bar settings=settings}}
    {{/foo}}
```

eg. in a hash scenario

```
foo-template.hbs
    {{yield settings=(hash color=color size=size)}}

my-route.hbs
    {{#foo color="blue" size=16 as |settings|}}
        #! How to change `settings.color` to "red" here before passing to bar ? !#
        {{bar settings=settings}}
    {{/foo}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need this, but if you need this you can achieve in multiple ways:

1. You can expose all the parameters and build new settings object:

```
{{#foo color="blue" size=16 as |settings|}}
  {{bar settings=(hash size=settings.size x=settings.x y=settings.y color="red")}}
{{/foo}}
```

This is the most explicit way but it is fragile when you add/remove new item to settings hash.

2. You can create a helper to override parameters:

```
{{#foo color="blue" size=16 as |settings|}}
  {{bar settings=(override settings color="red")}}
{{/foo}}
```

In the override helper you need to do something like that:

```
export function override(params, hash) {
  const obj = params[0]
  setProperties(obj, hash)
  return obj
}

export default buildHelper(override)
```

But this will also updates the `hash` yielded from the upper component. If you have the sibling of the bar components, they will also use `red`. So you may consider to create a shallow copy of it. Like this:

```
export function override(params, hash) {
  const obj = params[0]
  return Object.assign({}, obj, hash)
}
```

This will be safer.

Comment: Yes, an assign helper is best here!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a modified version of @ykaragol's answer.

Created an `assign` helper, which creates a clear mental model of the operation.

```
import { helper } from "@ember/component/helper";
import { assign as assignMethod } from "@ember/polyfills";

export function assign(params) {
  return assignMethod({}, ...params);
}

export default helper(assign);
```

Usage:

```
{{foo-component
            properties=(assign componentProperties barProperties blahProperties (hash onClick="foo" backgroundColor="#000"))
        }}
```